# How to share factory from a parent module to a child module?

Tags: angularjs

I have a parent module set up like so:

```
var app = angular.module("App", ["App.ClsEditor", "App.ClsNotes"]);

app.factory("Helpers", function($sce) {
    var factory = {};

    factory.createHtmlFromMarkdown = function(givenMarkdown) {
        var escapedHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml(marked(givenMarkdown));

        return escapedHtml;
    }

    return factory;
});
```

I have a submodule also defined like so:

```
var ClsNotesApp = angular.module("App.ClsNotes", ["ngRoute"]);

ClsNotesApp.controller("NotesCtrl", function($scope, $http, $routeParams, Helpers) {
    $http.get("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/arun-curriculum/Advanced-JavaScript-Two-Day/master/day_1/README.md")
        .then(function(data) {
            var markdown = data.data;

            $scope.output_html = Helpers.createHtmlFromMarkdown(markdown);
            Helpers.highlightMarkdown();
        });
});
```

It would make sense to me that the "Helpers" factory would be immediately accessible by the child module (App.ClsNotes). I get an error instead:

Unknown provider: HelpersProvider <- Helpers <- NotesCtrl

Any ideas?

Comment: You should be able to access it like this, it works for me.

Comment: Is there a reason to naming your sub modules starting with App.?

Comment: I'm just starting with Angular, but the reason I did this is to inherit the App module into the submodule.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to create a separate `angular` modules like here you can say it as `App.Utils` that can have the multiple components in it like `factory`, `service`, `filter`s, etc. By making a new module will be easier to inject it in any of module & the code separation rule also get followed by doing this.

**Code**

```
var utils = angular.module("App.Utils", ["ngSanitize"]);
utils.factory("Helpers", function($sce) {
    var factory = {};

    factory.createHtmlFromMarkdown = function(givenMarkdown) {
        var escapedHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml(marked(givenMarkdown));

        return escapedHtml;
    }

    return factory;
});
```

Then the `controller` module will include the `App.Utils`

```
var ClsNotesApp = angular.module("App.ClsNotes", ["ngRoute", "App.Utils"]);
```

Comment: @Arun does it helped you?

Answer (score 0):

You are requiring the App.ClsNotes module in your App module. If App.ClsNotes requires Helpers from the App, this becomes a circular dependency.

If you have helper methods, they should have no other dependencies from the app, though it is fine if they depend on externals.

This way, any module which depends on these helpers may specify the dependency without the risk of circular dependencies.